# Sqoop export from Hive to Netezza if column has array of values

Tags: hiveql, netezza, sqoop2, sqoop

I was trying to run sqoop export to load the Hive table rows into Netezza table.The problem is i have a few columns contains array of values and i  created DDL in Netezza for those column data type as varchar(200) and run the sqoop job but i am getting a error as bad rows reached limit.
below is my Sqoop job :

sqoop export --options-file 
 --direct --connect jdbc:netezza://10.90.21.140:5480/analytics --username sat144 --P --table analytics_stage  --export-dir /home/dir1/analytics/data  --fields-terminated-by '~' --input-null-string '\N' --input-null-non-string '\N' -m 1 -max-errors #0

My Netezza DDL below :
                                                                          CREATE TABLE analytics_stage
(
  id varchar(30),
   name varchar(60),
   dept nvarchar(99), 
   dept_id nvarchar(200) );

My Hive table column values are below

Row1:  20134(id)   sat(name)   Data_Group(dept)  [121,103,201,212,310] (dept_id)

Can any one help me on this? if column has negative values and Array of values in Hive table then what is the suggested data types in Netezza ??

### Sqoop Error log below

16/05/09 15:46:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/05/09 15:46:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1460986388847_0849_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

```
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.netezza.NetezzaExternalTableExportMapper.run(NetezzaExternalTableExportMapper.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Caused by: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

Answer (score -1):

Import/export functionalities are available from RDBMS to HDFS and vice versa. But while working with Hive, HBase, Hcatalog we have only one option for importing. We cannot export the data from Hive, Hbase, and HCatalog so far.